# Getting the most downvoted reddit comments of a week

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

How would I get the most downvoted comments of a subreddit, from the past week?

Currently I have tried:

```
for comment in reddit.subreddit('pics').comments.controversial('week'):
```

but it throws an AttributeError that says 'CommentHelper' has no attribute 'controversial'.
Help will be appreciated thanks.

This page on the docs shows the controverisal attribute:
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs that you linked, controversial can be called directly on the subreddit.

```py
reddit.subreddit('all').controversial('hour')
```

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.controversial